# Find limiting distribution of transition matrix and plot in R

Tags: r, distribution, stochastic-process

may I know how I can find and plot the results of the limiting distribution or a unique stationary distribution of a transition matrix in R? (my goal is to have a unique and constant result instead of a random result)

This is the P matrix used:

```
P=matrix(c(0.2,0.3,0.5,0.1,0.8,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.4),nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misspoke in my earlier answer.  Either the sums of the rows or the column need to all be 1 for a transition matrix.  It depends on whether you are using `v'P` or `Pv` to transition to the next step.
I'll use Pv.
For the limiting distribution to be stable, we must have:
`Pv = v`, or `(P - I)v = 0`.  So the limiting distribution is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1.  Then to be sure it's a distribution sum(v) == 1.
Since your matrix has rows that sum to 1, not columns, we need to use the transpose of the matrix to calculate the eigenvalues:

```
e <- eigen(t(P))$vectors[, 1]
e <- e / sum(e)
```

Gives:

```
e
[1] 0.1960784 0.5490196 0.2549020
```

To check this:

```
P=matrix(c(0.2,0.3,0.5,0.1,0.8,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.4),nrow=3,ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
ans <- e
for (i in 1:1000) {
  ans <- ans %*% P
}
ans
```

```
ans
          [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 0.1960784 0.5490196 0.254902
```

Same, so it's stable.
I'm not clear as to what you wanted to plot.

Comment: alright, if this matrix is used,  P=matrix(c(0.2,0.3,0.5,0.1,0.8,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.4),nrow=3,ncol=3), would it be possible to find a limiting distribution?